# Why is onFling() not working in ListView?

Tags: java, android, listview, swipe, onfling

**My app**
schows a `ListView`. When swiping right or left the `ListView` for a the next or previous day should be loaded.

**My solution**
I tried to use the `onFling()` methode to detect a left or right swipe. It works fine if I swipe on the `TextView` above the `ListView`.

**My problem**
Swiping on the `ListView` doesn't trigger the `onFling()` methode. Probably because my `ListView` is scrollable. Any ideas on how to solve this?

**OnFling()**

```
private static final int SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE = 120;
private static final int SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH = 250;
private static final int SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY = 100;
GestureDetector gestureDetector;


@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}

public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
    boolean result = false;
    try {
        if (Math.abs(e1.getY() - e2.getY()) > SWIPE_MAX_OFF_PATH)
            return false;
        // right to left swipe
        if (e1.getX() - e2.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
                && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Right   to Left swipe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            result = true;

        } else if (e2.getX() - e1.getX() > SWIPE_MIN_DISTANCE
                && Math.abs(velocityX) > SWIPE_THRESHOLD_VELOCITY) {
            //left to right swipe
            Toast.makeText(this, "Left to Right swipe", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            result = true;
        }

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Did you tried implement OnFly() in listView item instead of listView?

Comment: yes, didnt work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This solved my problem:**

```
gestureListener = new View.OnTouchListener(){
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event){
            return gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        }
    };

lv.setOnTouchListener(gestureListener);
```

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like an ideal use case for a ViewPager, which is meant for swiping left and right between different instances of the same fragment.  The ViewPager handles all of the gestures for you.

See [this guide](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide) and [this guide](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral) for examples of how to set up a ViewPager.

Comment: but I would need a tab for each day since year 2000, beacuse each tab would represent a day. is that really a good idea?